# ¿Como modifico el php para que aparezca en un solo renglon cuando hay una condicion?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, login

Estoy modificando el codigo porque se ve mal. 
Es un inicio de sesion. Quiero que aparezca

¿Ha olvidado su contraseña? | Registrarse

Asi en un solo renglon. Actualmente aparece en 3:
¿Ha olvidado su contraseña? 
| 
Registrarse

Css:

```
   .upme-login-forgot-link.upme-sidebar, .upme-login-register-link.upme-sidebar 
{
font-size: 11px;
}

a.upme-login-forgot-link:hover, a.upme-login-register-link:hover
{
color:#cc3b20;
}
```

PHP

```
 $forgot_pass = '';
    if ($widget_settings['display-forgot-password-link']) {
        // Forgot Pass Link
        if (empty($widget_settings['forgot-password-link'])) {
            $forgot_pass = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="upme-forgot-pass-' . $this->login_code_count . '" class="upme-login-forgot-link ' . $sidebar_class . '" title="' . __('¿Has olvidado tu contraseña?', 'upme') . '">' . __('¿Has olvidado tu contraseña?', 'upme') . '</a> ';
        } else {
            $forgot_pass = '<a href="' . $widget_settings['forgot-password-link'] . '" id="upme-forgot-pass-' . $this->login_code_count . '" class="upme-login-forgot-link ' . $sidebar_class . '" title="' . __('¿Has olvidado tu contraseña?', 'upme') . '">' . __('¿Has olvidado tu contraseña?', 'upme') . '</a> ';
        }
    }

    // Register Link
    $register_link = site_url('/wp-login.php?action=register');

    $page_url = '';
    $page_url = get_permalink($this->get_option('registration_page_id'));
    if (!empty($widget_settings['custom-register-link'])) {
        $register_link = $widget_settings['custom-register-link'];
    } else if ($page_url != '') {
        $register_link = $page_url;
    }

    $registration_status = get_option('users_can_register');

    if ($widget_settings['display-register-link'] && '1' == $registration_status) {
        $register_link = '<a href="' . $register_link . '" class="upme-login-register-link ' . $sidebar_class . '">' . __('Registrarme', 'upme') . '</a>';
    } else {
        $register_link = '';
    }

    $remember_me_class = '';
    $login_btn_class = '';
    if ($sidebar_class != null) {
        $login_btn_class = ' in_sidebar';
        $remember_me_class = ' in_sidebar_remember';
    }


    $link_separator = '';
    if (!empty($register_link) && !empty($forgot_pass) && '1' == $registration_status ) {
        $link_separator = '<label class="upme-widget-link-separator">|</label>';
    }
```

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Podrías poner el código generado, html y css, que afecta a los elementos que quieras mover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La propiedad que permite colocar en linea, es **display**

```
.upme-login-forgot-link.upme-sidebar, .upme-login-register-link.upme-sidebar 
{
font-size: 11px;
display: inline-block
}
```

la otra opción es colocar la respuesta dentro de un etiqueta div y usar la propiedad para este contendor div `{ display: flex; flex-wrap:nowrap }`

```css
.ejemplo-div{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="ejemplo-div">
  <div>tu respuesta </div>
  <div>|</div>
  <div>en diferentes reglones </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
echo ($forgot_password===true) ? "olvidaste tu contraseña?" :"No lo olvidaste" ;
```

Es un ejemplo

Comment: Tu respuesta es buena, pero puedes meterle explicación para que el usuario pueda interpretarla. Cuando puedas da un recorrido por este [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para ver más a detalle el funcionamiento de esta comunidad en cuestión de respuestas